# Is free will fundamental property of everything?

Tags: free-will, physics

Photon has a probability distribution of where it may appear if measured. Seems like photon itself chooses where to appear.

Comment: If photon was indeed "choosing" why would its choices be described by a precise probability distribution, the same for all photons everywhere in the same measurement? You seem to be confusing plain [indeterminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminism) with free will, which is much more complicated.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: To Conifold. I suppose a human could also be described by a precise probability distribution. For example, there is a probability close to 1, that a human will stay close to Earth for another 50 years or so.

Comment: Two questions: Wouldn't you describe yourself as responsible for your actions and making your own choices, even if - within certain boundaries - your behaviour is describable by probability functions? And on the other side of the coin - isn't it exactly because humans tend to show odd behaviour that is *not* fully describable in functions (among other reasons, esp. social behaviour and culture) that we assume a difference between indeterminate *things* and *persons*, however we catch there causality ontologically?

Comment: "Close to Earth" isn't precise, and "close to 1" isn't a probability distribution. If human behavior exhibited the same kind of statistical stability as behavior of photons psychology would be physics.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, photon is not "choosing" to appear at some point over other. Quantum Mechanics is ultimately a model of reality, and a damn good one, in fact, the most accurate model of reality we have at present. However, it is not reality itself.
Photon is simply following the laws of physics, which to us may forever be hidden, but we can still model their behaviour through probabilities, which is enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: Can we model behaviour of people through probabilities for all practical purposes?

Comment: behaviour of people is the result of super complex neuron activity in their brains. Sure you could tried to model their behaviour, but the bio-engineering difficulties you would encounter would be insurmountable.